Time Varying Electric Field in Quantum Espresso
Actually I am trying to get information about spin in graphene (a non-magnetic material), and the only way I know to get information about spin is by applying external magnetic field. No doubt such facility is available when working in VASP, but after a lot of research, I have come to know that there is no direct way by which we can apply external magnetic field in Quantum Espresso. And now, I am trying some other methods that can provide me information about spin, like by applying strain etc. One very solid method that I think can work) is applying a time varying electric field, so that according to Ampere-Maxewell law, this time varying electric field can produce a magnetic field (which at this point I do not know whether will be time varying or not- It will be constant, haha), and this magnetic field can give me information about the spin. I do not myself know whether I am thinking about it in a right way or not, but I think there should be some way to do it, as it is scientifically correct. And I am being very fundamental by the way! If you guys have any tutorial, file, or any other reading sources or Quantum Espresso flags, it will be a great help, I am a beginner and stuck on this point. Please help!

Does Quantum Espresso have functionality for time-dependent current DFT (TDCDFT)? My understanding is that regular time-dependent DFT (TDDFT) does not suffice; see e.g., these lectures.
